# "Oil blue" color

Tags: phrases, colors

Spotted a new collocation for the word `blue` today, when looking for a pair of jeans – `oil blue`.

Admittedly, they are probably just being marketing-minded, *inventing* (?) such a color of jeans. However, what gives?

The color itself doesn't look blue to me: [image: color]. Isn't oil supposed to be black or yellowish? May it be that the denim is very smooth (like oil)?

Is there a cultural meaning associated with this  word combination?

Comment: An oil slick produces many different colors including some that are similar in hue to yours: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Z5rqygK8YP8/ToDoGmeXMbI/AAAAAAAAAlQ/-dwEPLaMPQ4/s400/oil_slick.jpg

Comment: Maybe it's referring to the color of the jeans after you've done an oil change on your car.

Comment: @HotLicks, ha! :D

Comment: It should be noted that blue & violet pigments are the hardest pigments to produce, and several are recent inventions and tend to be named somehow for the process used to produce them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [this website](http://autoleak.com/Oil/Blue-Smoke-From-Exhaust.php) on auto repair says:

> If you are seeing **blue smoke from your exhaust** this means that your car engine is burning oil.

That's why this color is a very grayish blue; it's a hue similar to the tint you might see in car exhaust if the engine is burning oil, or similar to the color of exhaust you might see in a 2-cycle engine, where oil is mixed with the fuel rather than being stored in a sump.

[image]
Companies manufacturing paints, crayons, dyes, or fingernail polish are faced with the unenviable task of naming perhaps dozens of shades of the same base color, and they will often name some shades after everyday objects. Sometimes those names are simply reminiscent of the object they are named after, not exact matches. So *banana yellow* may not be the exact shade as a real banana, and *denim blue* might not precisely match your Levi's. In this case, this dull bluish green color had to be named something, and someone was evidently reminded of an oil slick or the blue tint of oil-laced exhaust.

[image]
<sup>Eggplant? Maybe not exactly, but close enough for a color palatte.</sup>

Comment: I like this answer best for its intuitive explanation.

Comment: Sorry, @mplungjan :)

Answer (score 6):

Here is oil blue as defined by  [Pantone](http://www.pantone.com/pages/pantone/colorfinder.aspx?c_id=3297)

`#638E8B`

[image: Pantone Oil Blue]

Seems this colour may have been with us for a long time [The Chemical News and Journal of Industrial Science vol 117, 1818](http://books.google.nl/books?id=5SAzAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA8&dq=%22oil+blue%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=dkpIUbbUBYWu7Ab5uYGoDw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22oil%20blue%22&f=false)

and seems to be recognisable in fashion although these are a little more turquoise in my opinion

[![Oil Blue Levi's](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E2%80%9Coil+blue%E2%80%9D+levis&rlz=1CDGOYI_enNL662NL662&hl=en-GB&prmd=ismvn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjI1vyrsrzfAhXRJ1AKHV8YCWwQ_AUIECgB&biw=320&bih=452

Comment: That's really not a bad match to the question's colour swatch.

Comment: That confirms that `oil blue` is a set phrase. Still unclear on the semantics and etymology.

Comment: So it seems, the term owes its origin to the chemical characteristics of the corresponding dye. Thanks for the factual answer!

Comment: I could alas not confirm this - there is an _Oil Blue A_ in Wikipedia but it shows the chemical formula and not the actual colour

Comment: This is an interesting puzzle. Two things are evident: there are shades of "oil blue" named because of their chemistry, and there is a shade of "oil blue" used in [fashion](http://www.flatspot.com/products/levis-commuter-series-511-shorts-performance-oil-blue). Whether the name carried over from the former to the latter, or whether the shared terminology is mere coincidence, that's harder to say. The Wikipedia page says the chemical can turn a "dirty green", but the pants look a bit brighter than what [this company calls _beach bum blu_](http://www.essie.com/shop/beach-bum-blu-p-10.html).

Comment: Beach bum blu, that's funny :D

Comment: I used to build cans of paint. The labels for the can were spat out along with the mix formula and receipt. Once, it took me a bit longer than normal to hand the paint to the customer. When the boss asked me what the hold-up was afterwards, I showed him the original labels, which read "Dempster Dumpster Green". This paint was for a million-dollar boat and I though it best to not label it that. The boss bought me lunch. So color names can also be pretty ad-hoc. But those associated with trade dress are tightly speced. When Kodak reorganized, there was a tussle over yellow and red.